# Remove white space from top in pdf

Tags: android, itext, pdf-generation

I am using **"itextPdf"** library to save my image in PDF format.
Everything is working fine but I'm getting white padding at the top of the resulting pdf.

```
Document document = new Document();
Image image = Image.getInstance(imagePath);
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight()));
document.open()
image.scalePercent(100f);
image.setDpi(300,300);
image.setAlignment(ALIGN_MIDDLE);
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiTXT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the automatic layout features of `iText` (which you are, because you are not specifically stating where you want to add the image), then  `iText` will always add a margin to the `Document`.

What you could do is add the image at an absolute position, that way you can avoid the automated margin.

You'll find this example from their website quite helpful:

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-precisely-position-image-top-table

Alternatively, you could also set the margins of the page to 0.

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/getting-started/itext-7/how-use-full-size-page

Keep in mind, I've listed examples for iText 7 Java. You may need to look around a bit to find the equivalent android API.

Comment: White padding still exist,it's width has been reduced after trying above solution.I have set alignment to 0 in all four direction and passed image width and height in scaleAbsolute()

Comment: Please update your example code and output. That way the issue can be diagnosed further.